# cant get text from an element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML setup as follows and am trying to use jQuery to access the textin the font field.  The table has multiple rows, hence the first line in the jQuery, for some reason I'm getting an empty string returned for the title variable.  Thank you for your help!

HTML

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="head">
                <a href="link" target="_self">
                    <p>
                        <font>SomeText</font>
                    </p>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
$('.table').each(function(){
    $(this).filter(function(){
        var data   = $(this);
        title = data.children(".head").text();
        json.array.push({
            "title" : title
            });
    })
})
```

Comment: A `<font>` element in 2015? That's a rare sight. Back on-topic, you should read more about what [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) do.

Comment: Use the right xml-node! `data.children(".head a p font").text()`

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with the class `table`? My guess if that your use of `.filter` - which is pointless in the code that you have provided - is resulting in the value getting overwritten.

Comment: @AndreLehnert, you do not have to get the descendant element in order to get the text.

Comment: sry. right. i wanted to show the structured way to this specific one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.head` is not a child of `.table`. So `.children(".head")` will not return any elements. You should use [`.find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) instead.

Also, the `.filter` seems unnecessary:

```
$('.table').each(function(){
    var data = $(this);
    title = data.find(".head").text();
    json.array.push({
        "title" : title
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your element with class head has no text in it, you need to adjust your selector to get the actual font element, like this:

```
data.children(".head font").text();
```